# Converting date in python

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

I need to convert dates that look like this "2/28/2012" into Feb 28, 2012.

Anyone know how to do this using string slicing, split, and datetime?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 2):

Just using `datetime.datetime`:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_str = '2/28/2014'
new_date_str = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%b %d, %Y')
>>> print new_date_str
Feb 28, 2014
```

`strptime()` parses the date string into a `datetime.datetime` object. `strftime()` converts that `datetime` back to a string in the required format.

If you want to do it with string operations:

```
months = {'1': 'Jan', '2': 'Feb', '3': 'Mar', ...., '12': 'Dec'}
date_str = '2/28/2014'
month, day, year = date_str.split('/')
new_date_str = '{} {}, {}'.format(months[month], day, year)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Try something like this...

```
from calendar import month_abbr

dateNonFormat = "2/28/2012"
splitDate = dateNonFormat.split("/")
monthFormatted = month_abbr[int(splitDate[0])]
formattedDate = "%s %s, %s" % (monthFormatted, s[1], s[2])
```

In this example your formatted date would be Feb 28, 2012

Answer (score 0):

You can use [easy_date](https://github.com/ralphavalon/easy_date) to make it easy:

```
import date_converter
my_datetime = date_converter.string_to_string('2/28/2012', '%m/%d/%Y', '%b %d, %Y')
```